# Name/principle for designing to accommodate multiple use cases?

Tags: heuristics, design-principles

Is there a name for the practice or principle of designing an interface that can accommodate multiple use cases or approaches that users might have?

For example, I am thinking of something like Amazon's product page, where they have many different types of content.  Not all users will read all of it, but the users who find a certain data point useful can read it.  Another example might be an item search results page that allows people to navigate many different ways depending on their preferences (filtering, sorting, etc), as opposed to a more directed UI that forces users to make specific decisions sequentially.

I have tried googling things like "flexible UI" or "emergent UI" or "adaptive UI" but those labels seem to be used for different things already.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases all pages accommodate multiple use cases. The examples you have given do justice to that.

I don't think there is any one name for it - its just UI